# Add Product Price and Add To Cart to WooCommerce Shortcode Output

Tags: woocommerce

I have a shortcode that I need help extending. Right now, it shows all the products in a list (ul). I need to add the price and add to cart for each product in this list, but I do not know how.

This is my code after some input from the answers below. I changed the `$loop` into `$query` and I added `wc_price` to the price, making it format automatically.

```
add_shortcode( 'product_list', 'product_list_shortcode' );
function product_list_shortcode() {
$query = new WP_Query( array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'product',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'hide_empty' => 0,
'orderby' => 'title',
'post_id' => 'id'));
$output = '<ul style="list-style-type:none">';
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
$product = wc_get_product($query->post->ID);
$price = $product->get_regular_price();
$output .= '<li>' . $query->post->post_title . 'Price: '.wc_price($price) . ' <a class="atc" href="'. $product->add_to_cart_url() .'">Add to Cart</a></li> ';
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
return $output.'</ul>';
}
```

All working fine now.

Comment: products are parts of WooCommerce, the product ID is post ID Wordpress side, to load the Product infos you need to load it: 

    `$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the price use the following:

```
// Using this variable you can get product information.
$product = wc_get_product($post_id);

// Get regular price even if product is for sale.
$product->get_regular_price();

// Get sale price if it is configured, else it doesn't return anything.
$product->get_sale_price();

// This returns the current price, if it's for sale it will show sale price, if not it shows regular price.
$product->get_price();
```

For the add to cart button, use this:

```
echo "<a class='button' href='". $product->add_to_cart_url() ."'>Add to Cart</a>";
```

I tried to transform your loop into a functioning product loop here:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_list', 'product_list_shortcode' );
function product_list_shortcode() {
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'post_id' => 'id'));

    $output = '<ul style="list-style-type:none">';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $product = wc_get_product($query->post->ID);
        $price = $product->get_regular_price();
        $output .= '<li>' . $query->post->post_title . 'Price: '.$price . '<a class="button" href="'. $product->add_to_cart_url() .'">Add to Cart</a></li> ';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output.'</ul>';
}
```

Screenshot[image]

Hope this helped. If not, let me know, and I will fine tune my answer.

Comment: Makes sense, but how do I add that to my existing loop? ```$output = '<ul style="list-style-type:none">';
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
$product = wc_get_product($post_id);
$price = $product->get_regular_price();
$output .= '<li>' . $query->post->post_title . $price . <a class="button" href='". $product->add_to_cart_url() ."'>Add to Cart</a> . '</li>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
return $output.'</ul>';
}```

Comment: Post the original loop in your question I can't read this

Comment: I've updated my question to include what I tried based on the answers given.

Comment: Theres so much syntax errors in your code its insane

Comment: I understand that, hence why I need help. I managed a while back to create the list itself. Now I am hoping to extend it. If you can help, thank you. If not, I understand.

Comment: I don't know if this will work, let me know

Comment: I get this: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_regular_price()"
But the code looks much cleaner and nicer, so thank you!

Comment: I had some typo's try to rerun the code

Comment: "Notice: Undefined variable: loop"
and: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function have_posts()"

Comment: Yes my bad I forgot to remove that

Comment: I just tested this on my local test env and it works.

Comment: Yes, it does after changing $loop into $query. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. make sure to mark the answer and have a good day.